# Connect two Azure VMs,across regions, via VPN

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

Can Site-to-Site Cross-Premises Connectivity technique explained in [this](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/cross-premises-connectivity/) document be used to connect two azure vms in different region, may be via an on-premises network?

Comment: Which document? I think you inadvertently omitted the link...

Comment: sorry, question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building a Virtual Network in Azure, it is created within a specific data center. If you take a look at the Virtual Network creation page (as illustrated in the doc you referenced), you'll see that you need to select the datacenter to associate the vnet with:

[image]

You may then add any of your cloud services *in that datacenter* to that particular vnet. There's no mechanism to span the vnet across datacenters.

Per your question about routing through your on-premises datacenter: If you had two VPN devices, you can establish VPNs to two vnets in two datacenters. However: You'd need to figure out some type of routing scheme to bridge the two. Also: You'd be incurring latency both between DC1 -> on-prem, and on-prem -> DC2.

You'd be better off just connecting via public endpoints and placing IP restrictions on the endpoints to only allow inbound traffic from the cloud service on the opposing datacenter.